# Why doesn't my following code run in any other IDE other than trinket?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ide

The following code works only on trinket and has many errors when I run it on other IDEs such as pyCharm, Jupytor and IDLE.

I have tried executing this code in online compilers as well but there are many errors.

There are zero errors when I execute this code in trinket.

```
from turtle import *
from random import *

def randomcolour():
    red = randint(0, 255)
    green = randint(0, 255)
    blue = randint(0, 255)
    color(red, green, blue )

def randomplace():
    penup()
    x = randint(-100,100)
    y = randint(-100,100)
    goto(x,y)
    pendown()

def randomheading():
    heading = randint(0, 360)
    setheading(heading)

shape("turtle")
speed(0)
for i in range(4):
    randomcolour()
    randomplace()
    randomheading()
    stamp()

def drawrectangle():
    randomcolour()
    randomplace()
    hideturtle()
    length = randint(10, 100)
    height = randint(10, 100)
    begin_fill()
    forward(length)
    right(90)
    forward(height)
    right(90)
    forward(length)
    right(90)
    forward(height)
    right(90)
    end_fill()

clear()
setheading(0)

for i in range(20):
    drawrectangle()
from turtle import *
from random import *

def randomcolour():
    red = randint(0, 255)
    green = randint(0, 255)
    blue = randint(0, 255)
    color(red, green, blue )

def randomplace():
    penup()
    x = randint(-100,100)
    y = randint(-100,100)
    goto(x,y)
    pendown()

def randomheading():
    heading = randint(0, 360)
    setheading(heading)

shape("turtle")
speed(0)
for i in range(4):
    randomcolour()
    randomplace()
    randomheading()
    stamp()

def drawrectangle():
    randomcolour()
    randomplace()
    hideturtle()
    length = randint(10, 100)
    height = randint(10, 100)
    begin_fill()
    forward(length)
    right(90)
    forward(height)
    right(90)
    forward(length)
    right(90)
    forward(height)
    right(90)
    end_fill()

def drawcircle():
  radius = randint(5, 100)
  randomcolour()
  randomplace()
  dot(radius)

def drawstar():
  randomcolour()
  randomplace()
  randomheading()
  begin_fill()
  size = randint(20, 100)
  #draw the star shape
  for side in range(5):
    left(144)
    forward(size)

  end_fill()

clear()
setheading(0)

for i in range(20):
    drawrectangle()

clear()

for i in range(20):
  drawcircle()

clear()

for i in range(20):
  drawstar()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing in RGB values as 0 to 255. By by default color mode in turtle is 0 to 1.0. So you need to set the color mode to 255 first before you try to set rgb values like that. or you need to set your rgb values between 0 and 1.0.

turtle.color says

```
    """Return color string corresponding to args.

    Argument may be a string or a tuple of three
    numbers corresponding to actual colormode,
    i.e. in the range 0<=n<=colormode.

    If the argument doesn't represent a color,
    an error is raised.
    """
```

color mode can be either 1.0 or 255. So by deafult colormode is 1.0 so color has this code.

```
   if self._colormode == 1.0:
        r, g, b = [round(255.0*x) for x in (r, g, b)]
    if not ((0 <= r <= 255) and (0 <= g <= 255) and (0 <= b <= 255)):
        raise TurtleGraphicsError("bad color sequence: %s" % str(color))
```

So lets say you pass 100, 100, 100 as your RGB, but color mode is currently set to 1.0. then color will multiply all your RGB's by 255.0. So your rgb will then become 25500, 25500, 25500. color will then check that  each RGB is between 0 and 255 inclusive, However since color multiplied all the rgbs by 255 since color mode is 1.0 all your rgbs now exceed 255 so color gives bad color sequence exception.

So either set color mode to 255 or pass in rgb values between 0 and 1

**255 RGB**

```py
from turtle import *
from random import *

colormode(255)
def randomcolour():
    red = randint(0, 255)
    green = randint(0, 255)
    blue = randint(0, 255)
    color(red, green, blue )
```

**floating point rgb**

```py
from turtle import *
from random import *

def randomcolour():
    red = uniform(0, 1)
    green = uniform(0, 1)
    blue = uniform(0, 1)
    color(red, green, blue )
```

As for it working in trinket but not others, maybe trinket is setting the colormode for you to 255